# Attempt to index field 'other'

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What is the problem here? This code is supposed to remove texts after I shoot it and at the same time increasing the score. Also, can someone explain what does the other.name actually mean? I don't quite fully understand it..(And yes its the first if statement that has the error)

```
function wordCollision(e)
    if (e.other.name == 'balloonText') then -- error here: attempt to index field 'other'(a nil value)

        display.remove(e.other)
        e.other = nil

        score.text = score.text + 50
        score.anchorX = 0
        score.anchorY = 0
        score.x = 200
        score.y = 50

        target.text = target.text - 1
    else
        if  (e.other.name == 'balloonTextt') then

            display.remove(e.other)
            e.other = nil

            score.text = score.text + 50
            score.anchorX = 0
            score.anchorY = 0
            score.x = 200
            score.y = 50

            target.text = target.text - 1
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could You briefly describe, what does Your function **supposed** to do, please? A little bit of context, where is it taken from might help either.

Comment: Did you mean that error at first `e.other.name` line? Edited, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means that there is no entry with key `'other'` in the table `e`.

If if you want to look up something in `e.other` you'll have to assign a table to that key:

```
e.other = {}
```

Using metatables, you could make it go automatically:

```
mt = {}
mt.__index=function(t,k) if ~rawget(t,k) then t[k]=setmetatable({},mt) end return t[k] end
e={}
e=setmetatable(e,mt)
e.other.name='foo'
```

Watch out with this though, because any lookup to a non-existant field will create a new table for it, which may or may not be what you want (aside of the fact that this overwrites any existing metatable on e):

```
for k,v in pairs(e) do print(k,v) end
print(e.bar)
for k,v in pairs(e) do print(k,v) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem could be that you have the `e.other = nil` in there, but don't reset e.other to something after, so when the `wordCollision()` gets called again, it is `e.other` is nil. Could also be that `e.other` is never initialized in the first place. Verify it is initialized somewhere before `wordCollision()` is ever called, and verify that it is re-set to something between two calls to `wordCollision()`.